# The readers/writers problem using semaphore

Tags: c, linux, multithreading

I'm a beginner in C and Multithreading programming.
My textbook describes a readers-writers problem, which favors readers, requires that no reader be kept waiting unless a writer has already been granted permission to use the object. In other words, no reader should wait simply because a writer is waiting, below is the code
[image]

where

```
void P(sem_t *s); /* Wrapper function for sem_wait */
void V(sem_t *s); /* Wrapper function for sem_post */
```

and 
The w semaphore controls access to the critical sections that access the shared object. The mutex semaphore protects access to the shared readcnt variable, which counts the number of readers currently in the critical section.

I don't quite understand what the textbook mean. It seems to me like:**if there is a reader, then the writer won't be able to update the share object**. But my textbooks says ***'no reader should wait simply because a writer is waiting'***, but when a writer is writing, it just locks the w which doesn't do anything to stop readers except for first reader?

Comment: Are you misreading? The sentence refers to a writer waiting, not a writer writing.

Comment: Please post code as text not screenshots. You can't copy it search for a screenshot

Comment: If you stop the first reader, you stop all readers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets say there are four threads `T1`,`T2`,`T3`,`T4`.

`Tl` is writer and `T2`,`T3`,`T4` are readers.

Now lets assume that `T1` gets scheduled first and locks the semaphore `w` and once done it releases `w`.

Now after this, lets assume `T2` gets scheduled and it locks the semaphore `mutex`,increments the global variable `readcnt` and since this is the first reader it locks the semaphore `w` as well.And releases the semaphore `mutex`.And enters the crticial section.

Now if `T3` gets scheduled, it will acquire the semaphore `mutex` and increments the global variable `readcnt`and releases the semaphore mutex then enters the critical section.

Now if `T1` gets scheduled again it cannot acquire `w` since it held by the reader thread `T2`. `T1` cannot acquire `w` until the last reader thread exits. If the writer `T1` is waiting and at the same time `T4` gets scheduled, `T4` will execute as it does not require to lock `w`.

So the textbooks says `no reader should wait simply because a writer is waiting`.

But as Leonard said in the other answer, `if the writer is already writing, you can't interrupt that process.` So `T2`,`T3`,`T4` has to wait for `T1` to release `w`.

Answer (score 0):

As in the first comment made, if the writer is already writing, you can't interrupt that process.  The case you need to deal with is if something is happening (reading or writing) and then a writer request arrives, and then a reader request arrives while the original lock is being held, you need to ensure that the reader request gets serviced first.  This is a tiny bit complex, but you're trying to learn, so thinking about how to do this is really the assignment.  Go for it! Try some code.  If you are truly stuck, ask again.